# Not able to hit breakpoint on Windows8.1 64 bit in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++, window

I am able to hit breakpoints within my application on windows 7 64 bit with VS 2010.
But when I try to debug same application in Windows 8.1 64 bit ,VS2010 able to find debugging symbols but breakpoints is not getting hit?

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Yes, deleted and created them fresh